# 'Adobe Acrobat Pro DC' - how to call preflight action by .net from action wizard?

Tags: .net, adobe, action, acrobat

how to call preflight action by AVActionPerformProc method from .net to be executed in Adobe Acrobat pro DC ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem, is to create preflight droplet which is an exe file, then to call it with a batch file or whatever ..